# SQL If "something" select count

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, count, sum

The output that comes from a custom view of mine is as follows...

```
Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4

xxxx    Cake    1      1*
Cake    xxxx    2*     1
xxxx    Cake    2      0*
xxxx    Cake    0      0*
Cake    xxxx    2*     0
Cake    xxxx    2*     0
```

and what i would like to sum is...

```
For every row, 
if the word Cake is found in Col1, then add the value of Col3 to Sum
else add the value of Col4 to sum
```

The resulted SUM from the view above, should be 1 + 2 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 2 = 7

Thanks in advance!

p.s. The Asterisks are added just to show, which numbers should be added to sum.

Comment: I wish I had asked this question early on in my SQL career...

Comment: @Preet: the "elseif" would suggest that you just add Col3

Comment: @strakastroukas: In fairness, there's nothing in your question to tell us that, BUT the elseif makes it unambiguous.

Comment: Oups! That was a typo deamon! I updated the question as requested

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
select
   SUM( 
     Case 
         when Col1 = 'Cake' then Col3 
         when Col2 = 'Cake' then Col4 
         else 0 END 
   ) as MySum
from TheView
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can just do

```
SELECT SUM(IF(Col1 LIKE 'cake', Col3, Col4)) AS MySum
```

I'm not sure about the syntax of other variants. Incidentally, the already supplied answer of

```
SELECT
   SUM( 
     CASE 
         WHEN Col1 = 'Cake' THEN Col3 
         WHEN Col2 = 'Cake' THEN Col4 
         ELSE 0 END 
   ) AS MySum
```

doesn't give the correct results - according to the specification, Col4 should be added when 'cake' doesn't appear in Col1, not only if it appears in Col2.

Comment: "Something along the lines of..."  :-)

Answer (score 1):

So based on Franks and Duncan's answers the following should be all you need...

```
select SUM( Case 
                when Col1 = 'Cake' then Col3 
                else Col4 END ) as MySum
from TheView
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #sample
(
    Col1 varchar(50),
    Col2 varchar(50),
    Col3 int,
    Col4 int
)

insert into #sample VALUES ('xxxx', 'Cake', 1, 1);
insert into #sample VALUES ('Cake', 'xxxx', 2, 1);
insert into #sample VALUES ('xxxx', 'Cake', 2, 0);
insert into #sample VALUES ('xxxx', 'Cake', 0, 0);
insert into #sample VALUES ('Cake', 'xxxx', 2, 0);
insert into #sample VALUES ('Cake', 'xxxx', 2, 0);


select sum(case
           when Col1 = 'Cake' then Col3
           when Col2 = 'Cake' then Col4
           else 0
       end) as [value]
from  #sample
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle Craig's answer will work or you could use a decode like the following:

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(Col1,'Cake',Col3,Col4)) FROM TheView;
```